# DC power supply by RF signal through a coax cable

Tags: power-supply, power, rf, dc, coax

I want to power a circuit which is only connected by a coax cable. Now I was wondering whether it is possible to convert a RF signal sent over a coax cable into a DC signal to save any bias Tees. The rf signal should be in the ISM band. I found rf to dc converters used for energy harvesting (e.g. http://www.powercastco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P2110B-Datasheet-Rev-3.pdf) but the output power does not fit my needs. I need at least 2W (better more). Or maybe is there a chance with a classical rectifier from a power supply unit to get a nice dc from a rf (I am concerned because of the high frequency of approx 800-900 MHz)? Thanks in advanced. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you can't just put the DC voltage onto the coax?

Answer (score 5):

You can put DC onto a coax cable, this is how many systems power their remote pre-amplifiers. Converting an RF signal into DC sounds nonsensical. Bias tees are a simple and practical way to connect RF and DC to a cable, with no significant problems resulting from their use.

Answer (score 1):

You surely do better by superposing the signal and the supply DC. The combination and the separation is so much simpler . It needs only a couple of LC filters. Your idea would be useful, if the signal was DC. But it's UHF, so use DC as the supply power and combine & separate it by using low pass filters (=one L, one  C)

Additionally the losses will be remarkably lower for DC.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wanting "phantom power". With phantom power you can simultaneously send a signal and provide DC power over a cable. Think about the low noise amplifier in a satellite dish - the TV box feeds electronics in the dish with phantom power and, over the same cable, receives the amplified signal coming back.

Comment: exactly that is what i want to do but I thought I can save some components like e.g. the bias tees. Further this rf signal will have some simple controlling fuctions so I have it anyway and thought I can use it in someway to also power my circuit. But it seems not to make any sense so I will chose the common way superposing the signal and dc.